Does the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic extend to general multiplicative structures admitting the factor-tree method of prime factorisation?
Context.
This paper says in its abstract that "any commutative Möbius monoid satisfies a unique factorization" and that "the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is a special case of the unique factorization theorem in commutative Möbius monoids" (both quoted by Wikipedia without citation).
The body of this paper doesn't seem to give a self-contained definition of a 'commutative Möbius monoid', nor an explicit statement that every 'commutative Möbius monoid' fulfils a Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. (My guess is that it leaves implicit that every 'commutative Möbius monoid' can be expressed as the "$R_1$" corresponding to some "combinatorial bisimple inverse monoid $S$" fulfilling Remark 3.1.) However, this later paper by one of the same authors gives a much simpler, self-contained definition of a 'Möbius monoid', and I believe it is easy to show that the type of semigroup that I define below is equivalent to a commutative 'Möbius monoid' minus the identity.
So if the terminology is consistent across the papers, then I think the answer to my question below should be 'yes'. But the words "if", "I think", and "should" in my previous sentence introduce uncertainty.
I suspect I'm not the only one finding things not clear (and lacking the time to wade through the details to gain clarity), seeing as the 'Generalizations' section of the linked Wikipedia article contains the aforementioned statements about Möbius monoids without any explanation of what Möbius monoids are, and that section has been flagged for lack of citations.
This is a sufficiently important and fundamental issue that I think it ought to be clarified in a self-contained manner somewhere.

The Question.
Given a commutative semigroup $S$,

for each $x \in S$, let $F_S(x)=\{a \in S : \exists \, b \in S \text{ s.t. } x=ab\}$;
let $P_S=\{x \in S : F_S(x) = \emptyset\}$.


Let $S$ be a commutative semigroup such that for all $x \in S$, $F_S(x)$ is a finite subset of $S \setminus \{x\}$.
Is it the case that for every $x \in S$, there exists a unique partial function $f_x$ from $P_S$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ (with finite non-empty domain) such that
$$ x = \prod_{y \in \mathrm{dom}(f_x)} y^{f_x(y)} \, ? $$
If so, what is the simplest proof of this that you can produce?

Well, existence of the partial function $f_x$ is immediate from the factor-tree method of prime factorisation that one learns at school, since every path down the factor tree must terminate within $|F_S(x)|$ steps. So I'm really just asking about uniqueness.

Finite semigroups have an idempotent element, so the semigroup $S$ you're asking about is necessarily infinite.

@Jakobian Thank you; is this meant to potentially help towards a solution? Or are you pointing this out because something I wrote gave the impression that I thought $S$ could be finite? Due to your comment, I realise that my product equation might look like I was assuming that $P_S$ was finite; so I've now clarified that $\mathrm{dom}(f_x)$ needs to be finite and non-empty.

Let $S$ be the semigroup obtained from free commutative semigroup on two elements $x, y$, divided by the congruence $xy\sim x^2$. I believe this is a counter-example to uniqueness and satisfies all your properties.

I was thinking about how would a counter-example look like, and I realized it can't be finite. So yes, it was supposed to be helpful for a possible counter-example.

@Jakobian For your counterexample, in other words, take $S$ to be the direct product of $(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1},+)$ and $({0,1},\times)$. I think you're right that this fulfils all the conditions, and yet $(2,0)=(1,0)(1,0)=(1,0)(1,1)$.

@Jakobian If you would like to write up your counter-example as an answer, then I'd be happy to 'Accept' it; alternatively, if you prefer, I can write the answer. In any case, please see the new question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4959809/222867, where I've added the requirement that $S$ is cancellative.
