Does the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic extend to general cancellative multiplication structures admitting the factor-tree method?
In the question Does the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic extend to general multiplicative structures admitting the factor-tree method of prime factorisation?, I asked whether what would seem the natural implication of a certain combination of heuristically formulated statements made in some papers is correct. The answer is no, and the counterexample provided makes use of the absence of a fairly natural-seeming condition (namely, the cancellation property). So now I'm asking the same question with this natural condition added in.

Given a commutative semigroup $S$,

for each $x \in S$, let $F_S(x)=\{a \in S : \exists \, b \in S \text{ s.t. } x=ab\}$;
let $P_S=\{x \in S : F_S(x) = \emptyset\}$.

A commutative semigroup $S$ is called cancellative if the map $x \mapsto ax$ is injective on $S$ for each $a \in S$.

Let $S$ be a cancellative commutative semigroup such that for all $x \in S$, $F_S(x)$ is a finite subset of $S \setminus \{x\}$.
Is it the case that for every $x \in S$, there exists a unique partial function $f_x$ from $P_S$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ (with finite non-empty domain) such that
$$ x = \prod_{y \in \mathrm{dom}(f_x)} y^{f_x(y)} \, ? $$
If so, what is the simplest proof of this that you can produce?

Well, existence of the partial function $f_x$ is immediate from the factor-tree method of prime factorisation that one learns at school, since every path down the factor tree must terminate within $|F_S(x)|$ steps. So I'm really just asking about uniqueness.

Let $S$ be the quotient of the free commutative semigroup on four elements $x, y, z$ by the congruence such that $xy\sim z^2$. I believe $S$ satisfies all of the conditions but there's no unique decomposition of $xy$.

@Jakobian As you can tell, I’m not so fluent in this game! I assume you meant “three” where you wrote “four”?

Yes, initially I wanted to say $S$ is a semigroup generated by $x, y, z, t$ with $xy\sim zt$

@Jakobian Ah, okay. I guess your counter-example is isomorphic to the subsemigroup of $((0,1),\times)$ generated by $2$, $3$ and $\sqrt{6}$.

Just like in $\Bbb Z,,$ in a comm. canc. monoid, if every element has a factorization into atoms (irreducibles), then such factorizations are unique (up to associates) iff every atom is prime $(p\mid ab\Rightarrow p\mid a,$ or $,p\mid b).\ \ $
